# What are the implications of setting FILESEXTRAPATHS in a .bb file (rather than a .bbappend)?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

The Yocto docs suggest that the variable `FILESEXTRAPATHS` should only be set in a `.bbappend` file, and by implication, not in a base `.bb` recipe:

> Best practices dictate that you accomplish this by using FILESEXTRAPATHS from within a .bbappend file [[source]](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/variables.html?term-FILESEXTRAPATHS#term-FILESEXTRAPATHS).

What are the implications of defining this in a `.bb` recipe? It works - but is it technically incorrect or unsupported? I'm looking to adhere to best practice.

Background: I want to use it to include a source directory elsewhere in a *mono-repository* (outside of the layer), in a case where setting `EXTERNALSRC` is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Admit that you have a .bbappend in an other layer with a files directory which contain your sources.
In this .bbappend file you want to add sources with SRC_URI+= "mysource" which is located in files/mysource.

In this case FILESEXTRAPATHS is used to locate your sources. Otherwise it may not be recognized.